# How to split responsibility of a product page?

Tags: scrum, agile, product-management, product-owner

In our organisation, the responsibility is divided based on modules. Let's take an example of an auto portal product page where the product page consists of many different modules owned by different product owners. Below are the types of content displayed on the product page and each type owned by a different PO.

- Product review
- Product images, videos and 360
- Product specifications
- Product Q&A
- Product offers and Discounts

Which is the effective way of dividing ownership of a product page?

**Way 1**: We have a dedicated PO who will take completed ownership of the product page. This will requires collaboration with other POs for respective sections.

**Way 2**: Joint ownership: Respective module owner will take care of the respective part on the product page.

Kindly let us know if is there any other effective way.

Asking this out of curiosity... How could the ownership be defined for the product pages at e-commerce platforms like Amazon?

Comment: Why do you have so many product owners for things that, as far as I can tell, aren't products? It seems like the cause of your issue is that you have people owning things at way too granular of a level. Why do you believe that it is appropriate for someone to own a product page, rather than the product (which seems to be an auto portal)?

Answer (score 2):

An effective way to define product ownership is to use *customer journeys*.

Each product owner is assigned one or more journey. Examples might be:

- Registration journey
- Onboarding journey
- Subscription journey
- Purchasing journey

By thinking in terms of journeys we give the product owner the chance to influence the experience of the customer. For example, a product owner could be given the objective of *improving the customer experience of purchasing a premium product*.

Comment: What happens when multiple journeys share a feature and the POs disagree? Scrum prescribes a single, authoritative PO.

Comment: Ideally the Product Owners will collaborate and come to a concensus approach. The Scrum framework does not describe this specific solution, but scaled agile frameworks such as Scrum@Scale and LeSS do go into it.